# Why would the same FB insights query work in a browser and Graph API Explorer, but return null with PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-insights

As you can see in this picture

[image]

- I have a valid long-life Access Token for my app (390068587730802) with the following permissions: ads_management, manage_pages, read_insights, user_friends
- I can use it to get data on another accessible app (50813163906) using the Graph API Explorer,
- $facebook->getUser(); does return my user id
- HOWEVER, I get NULL from the same request via the PHP SDK.

I have tested locally on xampp and on an apache server. I have updated the PHP SDK today to include the latest changes surrounding offline_access and long life tokens. I have read dozens of posts and FB documentation. I´m glad to read more you think will help, but please note that my token is valid, long lived, and I am successfully getting "/me" from the graph API. All of this happens under http or https.

**UPDATE** "*Facebook: Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.*"

As seen in this next picture below, I´ve var_dump´d the CURL options to verify the correct access_token and URL is actually being called. Furthermore, I can copy these urls directly into the browser and get complete data return!!

[image]

If during my testing I have created "two active sessions" - as some docs warn - how can you test for that? Most importantly, why would the same FB insights query work in the Graph API Explorer, but return null with PHP SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that "since=30 days ago" was giving a 400 (bad request) response. This error was not showing up in the CURL errors. Only via

```
curl_getinfo($this -> ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

When i changed

```
$period = "{$period} days ago";
```

to

```
$period = urlencode("{$period} days ago");
//or 
$period = strtotime("- {$period} days");
```

everything worked via CURL.